# Javascript encodeURIComponent() not encoding spaces

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with a text input with an id **txtPlace** that users will be entering input into that will be passed to the server as a url query. I'm trying to use encodeURIComponent(), but it is not encoding spaces. Here's my simplified code

```
<div class="searchBoxRow">
  <input type="text" id="txtPlace" size="55" placeholder="Enter place to search"/>
  <a href="#" id="btnSearch">Search</a> 
</div>
```

Here is my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
     $('#btnSearch').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault;
        var place = encodeURIComponent($('#txtPlace').val());
        var url = "http://example.com?place=" + place;
        document.location.href = url;
     });
  });    
</script>
```

If a user types **ACME Co.,New York, NY**, the generated url is

> http://example.com?place=ACME Co.%2CNew York%2C NY

See the spaces are unencoded? I even tried to add `place = place.replace(/\s/g, '+')` but that doesn't seem to work after encoding. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your assistance.

### Update:

**Blame Firefox!** Found out that the spaces were being properly encoded but **Firefox** is not displaying spaces as encoded even though they are. Tested in **Internet Explorer 10** and **Google Chrome** and they both display spaces in their encoded format. Thanks Adam for the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VYDcv/

Comment: place=place.replace(" ", "+"); no?

Comment: _Mirko_, if I place that after `var place = encodeURIComponent($('#txtPlace').val());` it doesn't do anything. If I change it to `encodeURIComponent($('#txtPlace').val().replace(" ", "+"));` the spaces are replaced with '+' but then that get's encoded as %2B. Better but not what I was looking for.

Comment: sure...
but you try, replace the spaces with + or %20 after the encodeURIComponent is the problem?
Look on my answer.

Comment: For reference, here is the [relevant bugzilla ticket](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=475896). It's worth noting that even though Firefox displays `%20` as space in the URL bar, copy-pasting the entire URL places `%20` in the clipboard, so this does not break functionality

Comment: Worth mentioning that whilst you noticed it as a bug in Firefox, in Chrome although my URL was encoded when hovering over the link, the URL preview in the bottom left was not showing as encoded (despite the fact it was).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're seeing, but `encodeURIComponent` does escape space characters.

See this fiddle, based on your code: http://jsfiddle.net/VYDcv/

If you type "Hello world", it will alert you with the space replaced by a `%20`.

Alert results: `http://example.com?place=Hello%20World`

When you set your browser's `document.location.href`, it may be changing the `%20` back to a space in the address bar, but it IS being escaped by the javascript.

Comment: _Adam_ it was working all along, I just happened to be using **Firefox v.20** and it wasn't displaying the spaces as escaped. Checked with **Internet Explorer 10** and it's properly displayed as encoded. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple solution for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
     $('#btnSearch').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault;
        var place = encodeURIComponent($('#txtPlace').val());
        place=place.replace(" ", "+"); //or .replace(" ", "%20")
        var url = "http://example.com?place=" + place;
        document.location.href = url;
     });
  });    
</script>
```

Comment: _Mirko_ it was working all along, I just happened to be using **Firefox v.20** and it wasn't displaying the spaces as escaped. Checked with **Internet Explorer 10** and it's properly displayed as encoded. Thanks